# How can I send values showed from the database to another php page?

Tags: php, mysql

I am taking values from the database and puting them in a table, the problem is that how can I show with form action the values of the checked checkbox?

I need to show in other page the `$row[1]` and `$row[0]` of the selected checkbox… I'm able to take the value of the selected checkbox but still need the variables `$row[1]` and `$row[0]`.

Thanks. Code below:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{          
    echo "<tr><td> "; echo $row[1]; 
    echo "<td> "; echo  $row[0]; 
    echo "<td> "; echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name='check[]' value='attended'> </td> ";
    echo "<tr>";
}
```

Comment: You need to set the checkboxes' checked property from the php code - if I understand you correctly.

Comment: all what i need is to send the row[1] and row[0] of the checked checkbox to another page ..

Comment: Use them as value in your checkbox, instead of _attended_. Or use the id of the database row and then retrieve the values from the database based on the id (key)

Comment: how can i do concaténation for the $row[1] and $row[0] in the value of the checkbox?

Comment: I would not do that, just have a single unique id set as the value of the checkbox.

Comment: If i need to see the value of the unchecked checkbox what should i do?